# Multiple Index Using JDBC River (MYSQL) in ElasticSearch

Tags: jdbc, indexing, elasticsearch, search-engine

I have used it successfully for indexing a single
collection using JDBC river. However, I can't figure out how to index multiple
collections from mysql.

This works for a single collection:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/employee/_meta' -d '{
"type": "jdbc",
  "jdbc": {
    "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectdb",
    "user": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "sql": "select id, name from employee"
    },
    "index": {
        "name": "employee_idx",
        "type": "jdbc"
    }
}'
```

When I add another collection for indexing using the following
command:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/jobdetails/_meta' -d '{
"type": "jdbc",
  "jdbc": {
    "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectdb",
    "user": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "sql": "select id, name from jobdetails"
    },
    "index": {
        "name": "jobdetails_idx",
        "type": "jdbc"
    }
}'
```

Nothing happens and the second index is not created. I am using the latest
version of the river from github on ES 0.90.0

Comment: I resolved that, I add autocommit true, index name same and type name different.

Answer (score 0):

I add autocommit true, index name same and type name different. The problem is resolved